# Help to prove/disprove a statement for infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the following assertion true? Justify your answer.

Suppose that we have series $\sum_{k=p}^∞ a_k$ and $\sum_{k=p}^∞ b_k$. Suppose also that $a_k = b_k$ for all but finitely many *k*. Then $\sum_{k=p}^∞ a_k$ converges if and only if $\sum_{k=p}^∞ b_k$ converges.

I'm really struggling to either prove/disprove this statement. Could someone please get me on the right track of starting? Is it related to subsequences or am I looking into the wrong section of this topic?

Comment: If it's a finite amount, you'll have a greatest $K$, so that the sequences are equal for all $k>K$. You can then split the partial sums $S_n$ in two for $n>K$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

1. For any $N\in\mathbb N$, the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges if and only if the series $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$$ converges.
2. You can prove (1) by looking at the definition of convergence for sums (the one with partial sums)

Answer (score 0):

Let the sets $A = \left\lbrace a_k \right\rbrace$ and $B = \left\lbrace b_k \right\rbrace$ denote those elements which are not equal for the sequence $\left\lbrace a_k \right\rbrace$ and $\left\lbrace b_k \right\rbrace$.

Removing these elements (which are only finitely many), let the new sequences obtained by $\left\lbrace a_k' \right\rbrace$ and $\left\lbrace b_k' \right\rbrace$. Observe that these two sequences are exactly the same ones. Hence, $\sum\limits_{k} a_k' = \sum\limits_{k} b_k'$, i.e., they converge or diverge together.

Now, adding finitely many elements will not change the nature of convergence (but only the limit, if the series is convergent). Hence, the two series mentioned by you converge or diverge together.